# Excel Conditional Formatting - Combinations

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-formatting

I have a spreadsheet roster. Each row represents a different individual in an organization that met once each month this fall (4 meetings total).

We used Excel to keep track of meetings, so there's 4 columns: "September", "October", "November", and "December". Whenever the individual attended a meeting, we put an `x` under the proper month.

We have other columns, too, and I'm familiar on using conditional formatting with other columns. The requirement for the organization was that individuals had to attend ***at least 3 out of the 4 meetings in the fall***, but it doesn't matter which months they chose to attend.

If the row has 3 `x`s in whatever combination over the 4 meeting columns (to represent having attended 3 meetings, whichever months they were), how do I make the entire row highlight green? I know how to do conditional formatting with simpler tasks, but am stumped... how do I code for at least 3 out of 4 boxes to have an `x`, regardless what combination of columns the 3 `x`s come from?

Thank you very, very much for helping. It means a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, if your four `x` values were in columns `C` to `F`, beginning from row `2`, you could highlight row 2 and apply the following conditional formula:

`=COUNTA($C2:$F2)>=2`

Then choose what you would like the conditional formatting to look like.

Finally, use the format application tool (in the home tab, it looks like a paintbrush), and apply that row to any other rows you would like.

The key to understanding this formula is the `$` character, which ensures that the formula will stay in a fixed Column, even when applied to other cells.  If we had written `=COUNTA($C$2:$F$2)>=2`, then the rows would also have been fixed, and every cell's formatting would depend entirely on the `x`s in row 2.

Comment: Hi Ben, thank you so much! That makes a lot of sense. I used the formula you sent, and modified so it's at least 3 "X" values, between columns E to H. Here's my formula. =COUNTA($E2:$H2)>=3) One more question, if you don't mind: I also have an =AND formula running. Here's my formula: =AND($B:$B="x", $C:$C="x", $D:$D="x", $I:$I>=12, $J:$J="")     Is there any way that I can combine both  my =COUNTA and =AND formulas so that both are necessary for the row to highlight green? Basically, how can I add the =COUNTA formula inside the =AND formula so --all-- the requirements must be met for green?

Comment: At the moment, the =AND formula is taking precedence over my =COUNTA formula. Basically, if all the stipulations given in the =AND formula are met, the row highlights green, even if the =COUNTA requirements aren't met, meaning that individuals who met all the other requirements but did NOT attend 3+ out of 4 meetings are still highlighted green, even though they should NOT be highlighted green. Is there any way we can make sure the stipulations within both the =AND and =COUNTA formulas are met before the row highlights green?

Comment: If you have two separate rules running, then either one might trigger, and I believe that the first rule takes precedence in the event that both are true.  If I understand you correctly, it sounds like you really should only have ONE rule running on these cells, and it should be `=AND($B:$B="x", $C:$C="x", $D:$D="x", $I:$I>=12, $J:$J="",COUNTA($E2:$H2)>=3))`

Comment: Yes! Thank you! That's wonderful. And, if I want the cells to highlight red if COUNTA is not >=3, then I just put in another formula with COUNTA < 3. That's awesome. Thanks so much for your help!